# Remap keys in Java Spark

Tags: java, apache-spark, rdd

I have a directory with some input files that I am calling with `wholeTextFiles` and it returns the full directory path as the key and the value is the text of that file. I want to remap the keys to just be the name of the file and not the directory path. Any ideas on how to accomplish this? Doing `JavaRDD<String>` on keys works but the last call reverts to original RDD. Any idea how to get around this?

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        SparkConf conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("Project");
        JavaSparkContext sc = new JavaSparkContext(conf);
        
        
        JavaPairRDD<String, String> inputfiles = sc.wholeTextFiles("input1");
        
        //Broken does not work
        JavaPairRDD<String, String> inputfiles = sc.wholeTextFiles("input1").keys().map(s -> Arrays.asList(s.split("/").get(7)));
        
        //get just the name of the text file. But this is not linked to original map and is not dynamic to pull last entry.
        JavaRDD<String> k = inputfiles.keys().map(s -> Arrays.asList(s.split("/")).get(7));
        

        JavaPairRDD<String,String> line = inputfiles.mapValues(s -> Arrays.asList(s.toLowerCase().split("\\W+")).iterator()).flatMapValues(s
-> s);

        line.saveAsTextFile("output");
        
        
        sc.stop();
        sc.close();     
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the java `split` method to get the last element of the path. Regarding spark, the java API is more constrained than the scala API. To get a `JavaPairRDD`, you need to use `mapToPair` and create a `Tuple2` as follows:

```java
JavaPairRDD<String, String> result = inputfiles
    .mapToPair(x -> {
         String[] files = x._2.split("/");
         return new Tuple2(x._1, files[files.length - 1])
     });
```